# SQL statement not grouping correctly

Tags: php, sql

I am doing a webpage of a food review, there is a page called top 10 where it will display the top 10 according to food review. I currently have this SQL but it combines all the dishes ratings and combine as a 1 dish. This SQL statement is being placed in PHP code.

```
SELECT i.path, i.name, AVG(r.review_rating), r.image_id
  FROM images i, review r
 WHERE r.image_id = i.id
 GROUP BY 'r.image_id'
 ORDER BY AVG(r.review_rating) DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page and [Ask] page soon.  'Not working' is not a good characterization of the problem.  With SQL, we really need to see an outline schema for each table in the query, with a few (2-5?) rows of data, and a description of what you're seeing and what you wanted to see.  It may be sufficient to simply give the table name, column names and sample values without a formal schema.

Comment: What are the quotes doing around `r.image_id` in the GROUP BY clause?  They appear to be single quotes, so you are grouping by a constant string, which might mean you only get one group because there's only one value for the grouping 'column' (value). If you were using MySQL (it's a good idea to identify which DBMS you're using with SQL questions), you might be intending to use ``GROUP BY `r`.`image_id` `` though frankly I'd use `GROUP BY r.image_id`.

Comment: And the old-fashioned `FROM table1, table2` notation was rendered obsolete by SQL-92.  You should not use it in SQL written 20+ years later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your sql schema it is hard to know exactly what you need to change it to. But it looks like you might want a to use a `JOIN` instead of selecting from multiple tables. Try something this:

```
SELECT i.path,
    i.name,
    AVG(r.review_rating),
    r.image_id 
FROM images i
JOIN review r ON  r.image_id = i.id 
GROUP BY r.image_id 
ORDER BY AVG(r.review_rating) DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

You'll also need to check that there are actually 10 different images (10 or more unique r.image_id's. You can check this by removing the `GROUP BY` and looking at the result).

If that doesn't work then post your schema.

Comment: i believe if there is less then 10, it will display how many there is right ?

Comment: @user3567749: If there are less than 10 rows, it will display all the rows available.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on `GROUP BY 'r.image_id'`.
`'r.image_id'` is a string and this makes `GROUP BY` create a single group from all the rows filtered by the `WHERE` clause.

You probably want `GROUP BY r.image_id`.

Read more about when to use [apostrophes, quotes and backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11321491/4265352) in MySQL.